# How to count previous days conditionally?

Tags: dax, powerquery

I have a table with 2 columns (DateKey and StoreCode) and I want to calculate age of each store in each day(AgeOfStore) using DAX. Actually I want to know how many days each store have worked?
For example, in 20210101, Store 1001 did its first work day and then this store in 20210102 did its second day,...

| DateKey | StoreCode | AgeOfStore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20210101 | 1001 | 1 |
| 20210101 | 1002 | 1 |
| 20210102 | 1001 | 2 |
| 20210102 | 1002 | 2 |
| 20210102 | 1003 | 1 |
| 20210103 | 1001 | 3 |
| 20210103 | 1002 | 3 |
| 20210103 | 1003 | 2 |
| 20210104 | 1001 | 4 |
| 20210104 | 1002 | 4 |
| 20210104 | 1003 | 3 |

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

DAX Measure

```
AgeOfStore =
RANKX (
    FILTER(ALL(tbl),tbl[StoreCode]=max(tbl[StoreCode])),
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'tbl'[DateKey] ) ),
    ,
    ASC
)
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Thanks for your attention but store 1003 opens in 20210102 and in this day AgeOfStore should be 1 !